# How to locally save a pdf file from file object?

Tags: python, django, pdf

I am trying to upload a pdf file and just save it locally received from a FILE request.

If it helps the file type returns the following:  class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'

```
def file_upload(request):
    lesson_file = request.FILES['file']
    # Save file to same directory
    lesson_file.save('file_name.pdf') #This is just an example of what I want to achieve
```

Comment: Do you need to upload the file in a `FileField` for a model or you're trying to just upload a file yourself? `FileField` will upload the file just by giving it the file object.

Comment: I am just uploading the file myself. Im not too familiar with FileField but if there is way to save any file object to a directory as is that would be perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple upload function:

```
def upload_func(file):
    with open('your/custom/path/filename.fileformat', 'wb+') as f:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            f.write(chunk)
```

Upload with a model:

model:

```
class MyFileModel:
    file = models.FileField()
    # ...
```

upload:

```
my_obj = MyFileModel.objects.create(file=request.FILES['file'])
```

You can use `upload_to` to change the path:

[FileField.upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)